# How to analyze time complexity here?

Tags: java, recursion, time

Assume you are playing the following Flip Game with your friend: Given a string that contains only these two characters: `+` and `-`, you and your friend take turns to flip two consecutive `"++"` into `"--"`. The game ends when a person can no longer make a move and therefore the other person will be the winner.

Write a function to determine if the starting player can guarantee a win.

For example, given s = `"++++"`, return true. The starting player can guarantee a win by flipping the middle `"++"` to become `"+--+"`.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean canWin(String s) {

    if(s==null || s.length()<2) return false;
    char[] arr=s.toCharArray();
    return canWinHelper(arr);
}

public boolean canWinHelper(char[] arr){
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        if(arr[i]=='+' && arr[i+1]=='+'){
            arr[i]='-';
            arr[i+1]='-';
            boolean win=!canWinHelper(arr);
            arr[i]='+';
            arr[i+1]='+';
            if(win) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works, but I'm not sure how to calculate the time complexity here since the function will keep calling itself until a false is returned. Anyone share some idea here?

Also during the search, we will encounter duplicate computation, so I think I can use a hashmap to avoid those duplicates. Key: String, Value: Boolean.

My updated code using a hashmap:

```
 public boolean canWin(String s){

    if(s==null || s.length()<2) return false;
    HashMap<String,Boolean> map=new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
    return helper(s,map);
 }

 public boolean helper(String s, HashMap<String,Boolean> map){
     if(map.containsKey(s)) return map.get(s);
     for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
         if(s.charAt(i)=='+' && s.charAt(i+1)=='+'){
             String fliped=s.substring(0,i)+"--"+s.substring(i+2);
             if(!helper(fliped,map)){
                 map.put(s,true);
                 return true;
             }
         }
     }
     map.put(s,false);
     return false;
 }
```

Still, I wanna know how to analyze the time and space complexity here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take that n = arr.length - 1

First pass you have n recursive calls. For each you have removed two +'s so each will have at most n-2 recursive calls, and so on.

So you have at most n+n(n-2)+n(n-2)(n-4)+... recursive calls.

In essence this is n!!(1+1/2+1/(2*4)+1/(2*4*8)+...) Since 1+1/2+1/(2*4)+1/(2*4*8)+... is convergent, ≤2, you have O(n!!)

Regarding memory, you have an array of length n for each recursive call, so you have n + n*n + n*n*n + n* ... (n/2 times) ... *n = n(n^(n/2)-1)/(n-1) and this is O(n^(n/2))

This is obviously pointing to not much better performance than with an exhaustive search.

For the hashed improvement, you are asking for all possible combinations that you have managed to create with your code. However, your code is not much different than the code that would actually create all combinations, apart from the fact that you are replacing two +'s with two -'s, which is reducing the complexity by some factor but not the level of it. Overall, the worst case scenario is the same as with the number of combinations of bits among n/2 locations which is 2^(n/2). Observe that hash function itself has probably some hidden log so the total complexity would be for search O(2^(n/2)*ln(n/2)) and memory O(2^(n/2)).

This is the worst case scenario. However, if there are arrangements where you cannot win, when there is no winning strategy, this above is really the complexity you need to count on.

The question of the average scenario is then the question of the number of cases where you can/cannot win and their distribution among all arrangements. This question has not much to do with your algorithm and requires a totally different set of tools in order to be solved.

After a few moments of checking whether the above reasoning is correct and to the point or not, I would be quite happy with the result, since it is telling me all that I need to know. You cannot expect that you will have an arrangement that will be favorable, and I really doubt that you have like only 0.01% of worst case arrangements, so you need to prepare the worst case scenario anyway and unless this is some special project the back-of-the-envelope calculation is your friend.

Anyway, these type of calculations are there to have test cases correctly prepared, not to have a correct and final implementation. Using the tests you can find what the hidden factors in O() really are, taking into account the compiler, memory consumption, pagination and so on.

Still not to leave this as it is, we can always improve the back-of-the-envelope reasoning, of course. For example, you actually do not have n-2 at each step, because it depends on the parity. For example for ++++++++... if you replace third +++--+++++... it is obvious that you are going to have n-3, not n-2 recursive calls, or even n-4. So the half number of calls may have n-3 recursive calls which would be n/2(n-3)+n/2(n-2)=n(n-5/2)

Observe that  since n!=n!!(n-1)!! we can take n!!≈√n!, again n!=n!!!(n-1)!!!(n-2)!!! or n!!!≈∛n! This might lead to a conclusion that we should have something like O((n!)^(5/2)). The testing would tell me how much we can reduce x=3 in O((n!)^(x)).

(It is quite normal to look for the complexity in one particular form just like we have O((n!)^(x)), although it can be expressed differently. So I would continue with the complexity form O((n!)^(x)),1≤x≤3)

Comment: How did this come 2^(n/2) for hash version?